# Placeholder is not working on text field in html

Tags: html, placeholder

Placeholder is not working in text field. My code is below

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="form-control" id="icon" name="types[]" type="text" placeholder="Icon Class"/></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" id="qf_name" name="types[]" type="text" placeholder="Name"/></td>
  <td><input class="form-control" id="qf_description" name="types[]" type="text" placeholder="Description"/></td>
  <td><a class="btn btn-info" onclick="addqf()">+</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteqf($(this))">-</a></td>
```

Please help me

Comment: it is working. see here https://jsfiddle.net/hx29mukd/

Comment: This seems odd ... Do u have ur <doctype> declared?